# how to send an email using Godaddy webmail in Springboot aplication

Tags: java, spring

When can successfully send email using Gmail but when I use Godaddy webmail I get the following:

```
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP 
host: smtpout.asia.secureserver.net, port: 465, response: -1] with root 
cause
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 
smtpout.asia.secureserver.net, port: 465, response: -1
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2106) ~
[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:712) ~
[javax.mail-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366) ~[javax.mail-
1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
```

Here is my properties file

```
spring.mail.host =  smtpout.asia.secureserver.net
spring.mail.username=  xyz@domian.com
spring.mail.password= ******

spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=60000
spring.mail.properties.mail.imap.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.imap.ssl.trust=*
```

Here is My code

```
//SendMail using java Mail API
@Autowired
JavaMailSender mailSender;

public String send(String to, String Subject, String Password) throws 
MessagingException{

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;

    helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

    helper.setSubject(Subject);
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setText("Your password is:"+Password);
    mailSender.send(message);
    return "false";
}
```

Comment: This is not about the code, the error message says it can not connect to the given server on the given port. Are you sure that the connectivity is ok? that you can reach the server on that port from your host? You can use nmap or any other tool to find out.

Comment: Yes i am using same smtp server and same server but serverport is SSL (Secure Sockets Layer)   in my outlook then is working  but in this code not working

Comment: Ok, but you are saying that ssl is enabled on imap, not smtp, but that be the problem? spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl=true ? instead of spring.mail.properties.mail.imap.ssl=true

Comment: spring.mail.properties.mail.imap.ssl=true  i use that but i get erroe message "message": "Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtpout.asia.secureserver.net, port: 465, response: -1. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtpout.asia.secureserver.net, port: 465, response: -1",

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to JAVA code, its seems to be issue on your server settings with SMTP protocol.

However I suspect you might missed some thing in your SMTP configuration in JAVA, I will suggest below pointers about it.

- Configure a local SMTP server as a relay on your locally, just to
  check you are on right track.
- You can even configure dummy server to trace the email request.
- Check your firewall settings as well, possible it might be restricted
  for other SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for appreciation, If this answer help you then you can provide your acceptance :).

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem - and was about to get crazy - when I found a working solution here in Stackoverflow, though I've lost the link, I'm sorry.

In this - legacy - project, I was using Spring 3.x. Mail was sent with org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl and configured like this:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.server.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${mail.server.port}" />
    <property name="protocol" value="${mail.server.protocol}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mail.server.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.server.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <util:properties location="classpath:javamail.properties" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Someone suggested to use this configuration:

```
mail.server.protocol=smtps
mail.smtps.quitwait=false
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

And that worked fine.

Beware the protocol is **smtps** in some properties but in others is smtp.

Answer (score 0):

Thakur!

I was getting the exact same error you are, but now I got a solution based on your code.

Try to add into your properties the following:

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=*
```

Your problem is happening because GoDaddy requires SSL in their connection requests, otherwise they won't answer your request! Also, I used https://www.smtper.net to test my smtp connection and see if it worked. You can use it to check if your problem is the missing SSL too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2 an works with this configuration:

```
spring.mail.host=smtpout.secureserver.net
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=your_email@example.com
spring.mail.password=your_password
# Other properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
# TLS, port 587
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
# SSL, port 465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

When you use gmail the protocol is TLS generally, but GoDaddy looks like use only SSL, so I comment the TLS config and enable the SSL config.

You must set de field **from** when you send the email (the same in spring.mail.username) or get an error:

```
SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
message.setFrom("your_email@example.com");
...
```

Hope can help you.

PD: after google a lot I finded the solution in: https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-send-email-via-smtp/